# Forceignore CustomMetadata on pull

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-metadata, .forceignore

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm) says:

> Sometimes, you make a change directly in a scratch org but you don’t
> want to pull that change into your local DX project. To exclude remote
> metadata changes, use the format `<api name>.<metadata type>` in
> .forceignore.

Also I've seen people replace statement like this `**PasswordPolicy**` with this `.PasswordPolicy`.
But when I add `.CustomMetadata` it does not work and sfdx pull operations does pull new/changed metadata.

My company adds custom metadata to the package as preconfigured project settings. But when you develop at scratch org you add/change project settings and you don't want to pull them from scratch org.

Obvious solution is to exclude customMetadata directory, but you have to comment/uncomment it when developing and when creating a new package. Is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug in the [Source Tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/a-deep-dive-into-source-tracked-projects.html) and you should raise a support ticket to make sure this is fixed for Custom Metadata records for the pull command for the **exclude remote metadata changes** case.
use

For a workaround, one simple technique is to create a different folder than your default `force-app`

Like You can call it `unpackaged` and have the records there and do not make it as `default` path as a part of the `packageDirectories` definition in your `sfdx-project.json`. Also do not specify this path in package generation.

Check [Multiple Package Directories](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_mpd.htm) to understand further.

Comment: Seems like moving metadata to another directory from "default" does the trick. Now .forceignore does block server metadata, but when I first push to the org my local metadata is pushed, because I blocked only default/customMetadata folder.